# Markdown issue with # in PostgreSQL code

Tags: bug, markdown

In formatted SQL code, the Postgres operator `#>` is currently misinterpreted as comment sign, which results in confusing display. Happened here:

- [Dynamically update JSONB rows - POSTGRESQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/282319/dynamically-update-jsonb-rows-postgresql/282360#282360)

I can use the  *```sql* or the *```pgsql* format specifier, no difference.

I *guess* this is another shortcoming of the (new) SE implementation of [hightlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) - which ***does*** have proper support for PostgreSQL and PL/pgSQL, [I looked it up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355073/169168). It's just not properly implemented here.
(In all fairness, there have been improvements on dba.SE since I posted [that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355073/169168).)

Of course, I don't actually *know* the reason for the problem. I only know I wish this would work properly on dba.SE.

The site is about databases after all. And Postgres is a major player. I don't understand why they would butcher the functionality of hightlight.js in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems fixed by now. Don't know when it happened, but on re-visiting this post the `#` character isn't misinterpreted any more:

- [Dynamically update JSONB rows - POSTGRESQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/282319/dynamically-update-jsonb-rows-postgresql/282360#282360)